# Can Alchemist use two different discoveries in the same bomb?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Long story short, while talking to my player he asked me this: can alchemist use two different discoveries in the same bomb?

For example, could he use *Acid Bomb* and *Immolation Bomb* in the same bomb? Is there anything in the rules preventing that?

We're using Pathfinder RPG.

Answer (score 8):

## No, you can't use more than one discovery on one bomb.

> At 2nd level, and then again every 2 levels thereafter (up to 18th level), an alchemist makes an incredible alchemical discovery. Unless otherwise noted, an alchemist cannot select an individual discovery more than once. Some discoveries can only be made if the alchemist has met certain prerequisites first, such as uncovering other discoveries. Discoveries that modify bombs that are marked with an asterisk (*) do not stack. **Only one such discovery can be applied to an individual bomb.** The DC of any saving throw called for by a discovery is equal to 10 + 1/2 the alchemist's level + the alchemist's Intelligence modifier.

[from Pathfinder SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Discovery-Su-)

## However!

Some bomb-related discoveries stack can be used together. Take a look at the [list of discoveries](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries) - the ones marked with a dot do **not** stack. As a rule of thumb you can have the bomb use one discovery that adds a special effect to a bomb and any number of discoveries that affect *how you throw it*, e.g. *Acid Bomb*, *Inspired Bomb* and *Strafe Bomb* can be used at the same time, but *Acid Bomb* and *Immolation Bomb* can't.

Comment: There's some title/body dissonance in the question that makes your bolded No ambiguous.  The title, which I assume you're responding to, thanks to the However, says "can I use two discoveries on one bomb", while the body ends with "is there anything in the rules preventing this?".  Just thought you should know I misunderstood the No at first, going from the question to your answer instead of skipping from the title to the answer.  +1, it is a good answer.

Comment: Beg to differ. There is a special case where alchemist can use discoveries dealing differents types of damages. Take a look at the surnatural ability of Goblin's Fire Bomber, Fiery Cocktail. It's the only exception I know, but it's worth mentionning.